# Ionic Cordova Build Android No installed build tools found

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, gradle, ionic4

I am having trouble building my ionic application on android on Ubuntu 16.04

This is step step what I have done in order to make it happen

1. Downloaded Android Studio
2. Downloaded the Android Sdk
3. in /.bashrc and /.bash_profile

   export ANDROID_HOME=$HOME/Android/Sdk

   export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/tools

   export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools

When I hit `sudo ionic cordova build android` I a getting this error:

> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> - Where:
>
> Script
>   '/home/iraklis/Desktop/mus/platforms/android/CordovaLib/cordova.gradle'
>   line: 68
>
> - What went wrong:
>
> A problem occurred evaluating project ':CordovaLib'.
>
> > No installed build tools found. Install the Android build tools version 19.1.0 or higher.

this here is my ionic info:

```
Ionic:

   ionic (Ionic CLI)             : 4.6.0 (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ionic)
   Ionic Framework               : @ionic/angular 4.0.0-rc.3
   @angular-devkit/build-angular : 0.12.2
   @angular-devkit/schematics    : 7.1.4
   @angular/cli                  : 7.1.4
   @ionic/angular-toolkit        : 1.2.2

Cordova:

   cordova (Cordova CLI) : 8.1.2 (cordova-lib@8.1.1)
   Cordova Platforms     : android 7.1.4
   Cordova Plugins       : cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard 2.1.3, cordova-plugin-ionic-webview 2.3.2, (and 9 other plugins)

System:

   Android SDK Tools : 26.1.1 (/home/iraklis/Android/Sdk)
   NodeJS            : v10.11.0 (/usr/local/bin/node)
   npm               : 6.4.1
   OS                : Linux 4.15
```

I am thinking that.. maybe this here in cordova.gradle

```
String[] getAvailableBuildTools() {
    def buildToolsDir = new File(getAndroidSdkDir(), "build-tools")
    buildToolsDir.list()
        .findAll { it ==~ /[0-9.]+/ }
        .sort { a, b -> compareVersions(b, a) }
}
```

for some reason cannot find the build-tools..?

> EDIT

I just noticed, when i do `echo $ANDROID_HOME` it prints `/home/iraklis/Android/Sdk` as expected but `when i run ionic cordova build android` after building it prints `ANDROID_HOME=/usr/lib/android-sdk` . How can i change that?

Answer (score 0):

you need to install the build-tools `25.0.3` (just assuming it may require these):

```
sdkmanager packages "build-tools;25.0.3"
```

or even several build-tools versions ...

```
sdkmanager packages "build-tools;25.0.3" "build-tools;26.0.3" "build-tools;27.0.3" "build-tools;28.0.3"
```

Comment: Doesn't work :(( nor with 19.1.0, 25.0.3, 26.0.3, 28.0.3.. Do you think that for some reason the cordova.gradle file cannot find the build-tools..?

Comment: @IraklisBekiaris I think that they are simply not installed... while "doesn't work" is not an error description. using the SDK Manager GUI in Android Studio would be the other option to install them.

Comment: sorry about that.. how are they not installed since i have download the android sdk and i have exported the paths? Is there something else that needs to be done? Thank you for your efforts

Comment: I just noticed, when i do echo $ANDROID_HOME it prints /home/iraklis/Android/Sdk as expected but when i run ionic cordova build android after building it prints ANDROID_HOME=/usr/lib/android-sdk . How can i change that?

Comment: @IraklisBekiaris that's where `sudo apt-get install android-sdk` would install it. does `which android` return something and can you run it? this would be the standalone GUI for the SDK manager.

Answer (score 0):

If you have brew installed, you may be able to just try this:
`brew install android-sdk`
This should then let you run
`sdkmanager packages "build-tools;25.0.3"`

Answer (score 0):

The proper command to install the appropriate build tools is

```
sdkmanager "build-tools;33.0.2"
```

(Of course substitute whatever version you want for 33.0.2)

Using `sdkmanager packages "build-tools;33.0.2"` now in 2023 gives a `package 'packages' not found` error.

Then, add the following to your path to your .zshrc or .bashrc file (or whatever rc file your shell uses

```
#Add Android Studio SDK to the Environment Variables
export ANDROID_SDK_ROOT="/Users/<your user folder>/Library/Android/sdk"
#ANDROID_HOME is deprecated. Do not use it anymore

#Add Android build-tools and platform-tools to the path
export PATH="$PATH:$ANDROID_SDK_ROOT/tools:$ANDROID_SDK_ROOT/build-tools/33.0.2:$ANDROID_SDK_ROOT/platform-tools"
```

(Again, be sure to substitute whatever version you're using for the 33.0.2 above.  And obviously  should be replaced with your actual user-folder name.)